# Why are there usually grids in front of sound speakers?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

Usually, the sound speakers have this metal grid.

[image]

However, not all of them have this.

Is there any purpose, maybe related to the sound quality, that justifies this?
Or is it only for physically protect the speaker?

Comment: It's solely to stop drunk college kids from destroying their speaker cones.   (or cats if you have one).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That crossed my mind :) but I want to check if there is really no other reason for having this

Comment: Yet another similarity between the behaviors of drunk college kids and cats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with sound quality.  In fact, the grid or covering is carefully chosen to interfere with the sound as little is possible.

Speaker cones must be light weight, so are made from paper or other thin and delicate material.  The grill is to physically protect the delicate speaker cone from getting dinged, a curious cat, or some moron with a poky finger.

The tweeter in your picture doesn't have a covering because it is significantly recessed and behind a rigid and narrow barrier.  Poky fingers can't fit in there to hurt the tweeter.  Also, the high frequencies that the tweeter produces are more susceptible to attenuation by a cover, and a cover would cause diffusion and alter the radiation pattern.  From the horn shape, it looks like the sound is intended to be directed in a somewhat narrow beam straight out.